# sandisk 32gb 3.0 otg gone wrong while using rufus then it says write protected

Tags: usb

```
[17801.915840] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[17801.916462] scsi host3: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[17802.922436] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra            1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[17802.923286] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[17802.923415] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 60063744 512-byte logical blocks: (30.8 GB/28.6 GiB)
[17802.924148] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on
[17802.924150] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 80 00
[17802.924371] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[17802.928666]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[17802.929770] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern SD card/USB pendrives, write protection usually means it has unrecoverable CRC errors, so the controller lock the whole device to prevent further data corruption.

Rufus does not cause this problem.  You just happen to use rufus to write significant amount of data on the drive when it reaches the end of life.

All you can do is replacing the drive or RMA.

Comment: +1; @SagarVishal, If you want a deeper analysis of your problem, see also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035).